# Mocking a class inside an Android app - not in unit test scope

Tags: android, design-patterns, mocking, mockito, wrapper

I would like to mock an object/class inside my app (this class interacts with a 3rd party library) and I would like to be able to run my app regardless of the actual response I get from the 3rd party library.

I would like to set my own responses to the methods called.

I tried to use mockito and compile it regularly (I have used compile instead of testCompile).

I have encountered different errors with different version when trying to invoke spy or mock static creation of the mock object.

My questions:

1. Is Mockito suitable for running inside the app or it is built only for unit testing? if it is suitable , is there a link for a boilerplate code doing that for android ?
2. Is there any other better solution/framework other than writing the mock my self? (before I choose implementing a proxy pattern or something similar)

Comment: mocking frameworks are definately not to be used in production..

Comment: since the 3rd party library is a bottleneck in development (it uses proprietary HW devices) I must mock it to speed up development

Answer (score 2):

> Is Mockito suitable for running inside the app or it is built only for unit testing?

No. plain and simple.

> Is there any other better solution/framework other than writing the mock my self? (before I choose implementing a proxy pattern or something similar)

This exposes a tight coupling to the 3rd part dependency. Consider encapsulating 3rd party dependencies behind abstractions you control to allow greater flexibility.

That way you can swap in your own mocks/stubs/fakes to speed up development.

Review your current design choice and aim for code that is loosely coupled. It will benefit you and who ever has to maintain the code in the future.